# Multiple google map in one page with marker generated by reading lat and lng from page dom

Tags: google-maps-markers

Google map is working as expected but when i try to add multiple google map with my existing code i struggle and i am new to js and google map api. Any help on this is highly appreciated. I am going to add my codepen link here please help me with it.

Below is my codepen link:
http://codepen.io/suman/pen/dWMEmp

Existing code:

```
var googleMap = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this;

    if ($("#map").length > 0) {
      self.triggerMap();
    }
  },

  triggerMap: function() {
    var self = this;

    // Define your locations: HTML content for the info window, latitude, longitude
    // var locations = [{
    //   info: {
    //     name: 'name 1',
    //     url: 'http://google.co.uk',
    //     casualties: '54,000'
    //   },
    //   lat: 51.507351,
    //   lng: -0.12775
    // }];

    var e = [];
    $(".mapMarker").each(function() {
      var self = $(this),
        mainLink = $(".mapLink"),
        lat = self.find(mainLink).data("lat"),
        lng = self.find(mainLink).data("lng"),
        name = self.find(mainLink).text(),
        url = self.find(mainLink).attr("href"),
        casualties = self.find(".casualties").text();

      e.push({
        info: {
          name: name,
          casualties: casualties,
          url: url
        },
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      });
    });

    // Initiate the map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      scrollwheel: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      zoom: 8
    });

    // Initiate the info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Initiate the bounds function
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Loop through all the locations to add markers & info windows
    e.forEach(function(location, i) {
      // New marker based on the lat & lng of location
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng),
        map: map,
        icon: "http://maplacejs.com/website/images/red-dot.png"
      });

      // Extend the bounds with the new position used in the marker above
      bounds.extend(marker.position);

      // html for the info window
      var infoContent =
        '<div class="info-content"><h4><a href="' +
        location.info.url +
        '">' +
        location.info.name +
        "</a></h4>" +
        "<p>" +
        location.info.casualties +
        "</p></div>";

      // Listen out for when the marker is clicked and generate the info window
      google.maps.event.addListener(
        marker,
        "click",
        (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          };
        })(marker, i)
      );
    });

    // Now we have all the locations added to the bounds variable, tell the map to fit them all in.
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
      if (map.getZoom() > 10) map.setZoom(10);
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
  }
};

googleMap.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this one..

For the html part you need 2 or more divs to contain maps

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>
```

In your javascript u need to create 2 or more maps

```
// Create map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);
```

And in your css you can apply separate styles if needed to each map

```
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 48%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#map2 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 48%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Karthik nagarajan thanks for you help but if you look into my code and how it structure and generates marker we may need different approach but i little bit understand your point. Hopefully, we can find solution for this problem. you can look into the codepen link and if we can solve it that would be great help.